# Insert double quotes in a macro for pragma in C

Tags: c, macros, pragma

I'm trying to create a macro in C in order to create the correct pragma declaration.

```
_pragma(section .BLOCK1) //Correct but deprecated
_pragma(section ".BLOCK1") //Correct without warning
```

Following code is working, but the compiler gives me a warning (deprecated declaration):

```
#define DO_PRAGMA(x) _Pragma(#x)

#define PRAGMA(number) \
DO_PRAGMA(section .BLOCK##number)

PRAGMA(1)
```

How I can include the double quotes in the macro?
I have already tried inserting "\"", but it is not working because the string is interpreted directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass this to a helper macro which expands and stringifies the arguments.

```c
#define _stringify(_x)  #_x

#define DO_PRAGMA(a) _Pragma(_stringify(a))

#define PRAGMA(number) \
    DO_PRAGMA(section _stringify(.BLOCK##number))
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for this, the compiler doesn't return any error, but if I try to print the resulting string with printf I got follwing string  `section _stringify(.BLOCK123) ` (also the macro expansion of Eclipse return the same). I'm not sure if this is correct or not (maybe the compiler can resolve it in a second step).

Comment: you can inspect the expansion with `gcc -E`

Comment: @Andrea, this should work, `PRAGMA(1)` should expand to `_Pragma("section \".BLOCK1\"")` so I think that's what you need.

Comment: @Andrea, dont forget to upvote and/or accept if the answer helps you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to add double quotes to a macro is indeed to use backslash i.e.:

```
#define STRING "\"string\""
```

`"string"` is now stored in `STRING`.

To concatenate a number into your macro string you can do something like, but it needs to be stored in non const char array:

```
#define STRING "section \".BLOCK%d\""
#define CONV(str, n) sprintf(str, STRING, n)
//...
char str [50];
CONV(str, 1);
DO_PRAGMA(str);
//...
```

If you haven't already, check [pragma documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html) and [this usage example](http://books.gigatux.nl/mirror/cinanutshell/0596006977/cinanut-CHP-14-SECT-7.html).

Comment: Hello, yes, as I written I have already tried it, but it is not working because the macro DO_PRAGMA takes it literally. I have already checked the documentation, but it is not helpful in my case because my string is not fixed, but as to be resolved by the macro (see the ## operator).

Comment: @Andrea, I added an option to concatenate a numbers into macros, not quite the same but check if it fits your needs.